# Where can I find leiningen's profiles.clj on Mac?

Tags: clojure

I am unable to locate the Leiningen profiles.clj file under .lein on my Mac. I am looking to use a previous version of Luminus by adding the following code to the profiles.clj:

```
 :user {:plugins [[luminus/lein-template "1.16.7"]]}
```

So when i run:

```
lein new luminus myproject
```

I use the 1.16.7 template version of luminus.

Thanks

Comment: It's under .lein in my home directory on my Mac.

Comment: What is the contents of the file?

Comment: I have managed to resolve this by creating my own profiles.clj and adding  {:user {:plugins [[luminus/lein-template "1.16.7"]]}}

Comment: I don't use Luminus.  It's just the Leiningen default: `{:user {} :repl {:dependencies [] :repl-options {}}}`.  Pretty exciting, huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be located at `~/.lein/profiles.clj` as you're suggesting.

However, if you've not had need for profiles.clj before, then you have to create it yourself, which is probably why you can't find it.

I set up a new machine recently, and I'm pretty sure that I created the file myself.